# How do I use numbers in a tkinter canvas and add to them?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am currently a beginner programmer and im learning the basics of python. I made a game called "Bounce", and i am trying to create a score counter. I have tried to use the canvas.create_text() function, but it isn't working. I am not sure on how to change the text into a number that can change every time the ball hits the paddle. i need help. Here is my code for anyone that needs it:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
from time import sleep 

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False 

def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
        if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
            return True
    return False

def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
        self.y = 3
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
        self.hit_bottom = True
    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
        self.y = -3
    if pos[0] <= 0:
        self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
        self.x = -3

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", self.turn_right)

def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[0] <= 0:
        self.x = 0
    elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
        self.x = 0
        
def turn_left(self, evt):
    self.x = -2

def turn_right(self, evt):
    self.x = 2

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Bounce!")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, "blue")
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, "red")

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

if ball.hit_bottom == True:
    canvas.create_text(250, 150, text="Game Over!", fill="red", font=("Courier", 50))
    canvas.create_text(250, 200, text="The Ball Hit the Floor", fill="black", font=("Courier", 25))
```

Comment: There is a lot of wrong doing in your code. But the reason why your code never goes through `if ball.hit_bottom == True:` is because the indention is wrong. You need to put it in the whileloop.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. It must be just here, because it is within the while loop in my code in my environment.